# Azure Service Bus - MaxConcurrentCalls=1 - The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus

I am using Azure Service Bus and I have the code below (c# .NetCore 3.1). I am constantly getting the error "*The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.*" when I call "CompleteAsync"

As you can see in the code I have the "ReceiveMode.PeekLock", "AutoComplete = false" and MaxAutoRenewDuration to 5 min. The code that handles the message completes in less than 1 second and I still get that error every single time.

What drove me crazy is that after hours reading posts, rewriting my code and a lot of "try and error" I decided to increase the MaxConcurrentCalls from 1 to 2 and magically the error disappeared.

Does anybody knows what is going on here?

```
public void OpenQueue(string queueName)
{
  var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(exceptionReceivedEventArgs =>
  {
    Log.Error($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  });
  messageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
  messageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
  messageHandlerOptions.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

  messageReceiver = queueManagers.OpenReceiver(queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
  messageReceiver.RegisterMessageHandler(async (message, token) =>
  {
    if (await ProcessMessage(message)) //really quick operation less than 1 second
    {
      await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
    else
    {
      await messageReceiver.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
  }, messageHandlerOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing the solution for my problem as it may help others.

Turns out the root cause of the problem was a quite basic mistake, but the error got me really confused.
The method *OpenQueue* was called more than once on the same class instance (multiple queues scenario) what was a mistake. The behavior was quite weird. Looks like queueManagers registered all queues as expected but the token got overwritten causing it to always be invalid.

When I wrote:

> I decided to increase the MaxConcurrentCalls from 1 to 2 and magically the error disappeared.

Later that statement proved to be incorrect. When I enabled multiple queues that failed miserably.

The block of code I posted here is actually working. What was around it was broken. I was trying to gain some time and ended up writing bad code. I fixed my design to manage things properly and everything is now running smooth.

Answer (score 2):

> I decided to increase the MaxConcurrentCalls from 1 to 2 and magically the error disappeared.

Concurrency and lock duration is not the only variables in the equation. This sounds like a prefetch issue. If enabled, more messages are prefetched than processed to save on the latency and the roundtrips. If the prefetch is too aggressive, messages that are pre-fetched and waiting are still going to be processed, and while the processing would normally be short enough, the combined time of waiting for processing and the actual processing would exceed the lock duration.

I would suggest to:

1. Increase `MaxLockDuration` on the queue
2. Validate the prefetch count

Regarding `MaxLockDuration` vs `MaxAutoRenewDuration` these two are tricky. While the first is guaranteed, the second is **not** and is a best-effort by the client.

Comment: That statement I wrote was incorrect. I posted the answer to my question. It was my mistake.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. This was the answer to my issue. I have one or two MaxConcurentCalls and a PrefetchCount of 100. After so many successful records, the app stopped confirming the messages -- they still processed but didn't leave the queue. Adjusting PrefetchCount fixed it.